# SwiftUI NavigationLink causes a push to happen, then it pops after completion, then pushes again for good

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm having some strange animation effects in my SwiftUI code. In my `sheet` that's presented, my root view the `SafariQuickTopicView` code is below.

When I tap any of the buttons in the my `horizontalScroll`, `actionState` will update to `readyToTransition`, the view will push then on completion it'll temporarily pop back to the previous view and then push again for good to my new `View`.

Any idea why it's doing this? I thought it might be related to my `SafariView` which I've removed from the code below as it's still happening. That view is a `SafariViewController` that conforms to `UIViewRepresentable`, for what it's worth.

Thanks

```
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @EnvironmentObject var state: AppState

    @Binding var articleDisplayed: Bool

    @State var actionState: ActionState? = .setup

    // MARK: - Body

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                horizontalScroll
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: passButton)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Subviews

    private var horizontalScroll: some View {
        return ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<self.multiTopics.endIndex) { i in
                    NavigationLink(destination: self.tagView, tag: .readyForTransition, selection: self.$actionState) {
                        MultiTopicView(
                            articleDisplayed: self.$articleDisplayed,
                            actionState: self.$actionState,
                            topics: self.multiTopics[i],
                            setTopics: { self.topicsWereSet(topics: self.multiTopics[i]) }
                        )
                    }
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: topicsView) {
                    Text("More Topics")
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 12)
            .frame(maxHeight: 55)
        }
        .background(Color.white)
        .padding(.top, -11)
    }

struct MultiTopicView: View {

    @Binding var articleDisplayed: Bool
    @Binding var actionState: ActionState?
    let topics: [Topic]
    let setTopics: () -> Void

    var topicNames: String {
        topics.map { $0.name }.joined(separator: ", ")
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.actionState = .readyForTransition
        }) {
            Text(self.topicNames)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not testable but as I see all your links have same tag, so activating one, you activate them all... after this everything is unpredictable and can result in anything. Tag has to be unique per-link, it like identifier - to designate which link should be activated.

Comment: Where are you seeing that tags need to be unique? I'm not finding that in Apple's docs

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the same tag for every NavigationLink.

> Bind the NavigationLink to a selection variable and provide a tag of the variable’s type. Setting the value of selection to tag performs the navigation.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

If you use the same tag, all the navigation links will perform the navigation at the same time.
This is undefined behaviour.